# What is an "import" called?

Tags: java, import, terminology

It is not a statement nor an expression.

What is that called then? A directive?

Comment: @SLaks... I don't know.. mmhh reserved word maybe?

Comment: Here's referred as an statement: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html  :(

Comment: Very commonly referred to as an "import statement", it seems: http://www.google.fi/search?q=java+%22import+statement vs http://www.google.fi/search?q=java+%22import+declaration

Comment: @Jonik Yeap, I .. call it like that also ( or directive sometimes )  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774479/only-one-public-class-per-file/2774549#2774549  But not necessarily that's correct. Thanks for the edit btw.

Comment: Great question. Even JLS 7.5.1 slipped up and says "Note that an `import` **statement** cannot import a subpackage, only a type." If you trace the grammatical production, though, you easily confirm that it's not in fact a statement (obviously!).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"declaration"

#### See also

- [JLS 7.5. Import Declaration](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5)

  - [7.5.1 Single-Type-Import Declaration](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5.1)
  - [7.5.2 Type-Import-on-Demand Declaration](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5.2)
  - [7.5.3 Single Static Import Declaration](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5.3)
  - [7.5.4 Static-Import-on-Demand Declaration](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5.4)

Answer (score 6):

It's called a [**Declaration**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5).

Answer (score 1):

In the general scope, it is a directive.

Within Java, classes have a tight relationship between their declaration and their containing file (known as a compiler unit in Java's architecture).  However, the import statement pre-dates Java.

When it was used in the C language, it was a declaration to the pre-processor (a component that is not existent in Java, to "paste" the file at "this location".  This allowed one to "use" declarations without defining them (important for structuring C source code) by pasting in the "header" file which contained all the declarations for an "definition" file which would be linked in at a later date.  This style of layout allowed implementations to share each others *declared* types without being influence by the actual implementation (known as the type *definition*).

Java inherited from C's legacy, so they used the "import" keyword to locate the type *declaration*; but Java doesn't really have independent declarations and definitions, opting for the declaration to be "read" from the definition.  This was in an attempt to prevent a common C / C++ failure (that of compiling against on version of declarations, to have the code mysteriously fail with an almost-the-same set of definitions (built off a newer or later version of declarations).

> So, for C/C++ - A preprocessor directive (equivalent to a preprocessor
>   command).
>
> And for Java - A declaration, as the directive matches a command to a
>   preprocessor that no longer exists, under a restrictive layout that
>   only permits one declaration per included file.