# compiler error: "Cursor cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, android

I'm messing around with the Notepad exercise 1. When I create the fillData method, I get an error that "Cursor cannot be resolved to a type"

Here's my code:

```
private void fillData() {
    //get notes from DB and create item list
    Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] from = new String [] { NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };

    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}
```

Do I need to import the cursor class at the top of my java file? If so, how?

Comment: @xscott the `import`  is actually a declaration ( I thought for a while it was an statement also  )  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774747/what-is-an-import-called

Comment: @Falmarri yes im using eclipse

Comment: You should see a little red line under `Cursor c` and the context menu will tell you what to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely you need to add an `import` declaration

Like:

```
import android.database.Cursor;
```

Comment: Thanks. I just let eclipse do the work. Right-clicked the error and had it import the proper classes.

Comment: That and import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter; apparently

Comment: You could just hit Ctrl+Shift+O to import all the necessary packages if you're using eclipse.